# C++ `vector iterators incompatible` error only in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class representing a string of space-delimited words via a vector of those words and an iterator over the vector.

```
class WordCrawler{
public:
    WordCrawler(std::string, bool reversed=false);
    WordCrawler& operator--();
    std::string operator*  () const;

    bool atBeginning() const;
private:
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
};
```

I am trying to print out the words in reverse order, using this function:

```
void print_in_reverse(std::string in) {
    WordCrawler wc = WordCrawler(in, true);
    while (!wc.atBeginning()) {
        --wc;
        std::cout << *wc << " ";
    } 
}
```

I construct my `WordCrawler` object with this constructor:

```
WordCrawler::WordCrawler(std::string in, bool reversed) {
    std::istringstream iss(in);
    std::string token;
    while (std::getline(iss, token, ' '))
    {
        words.push_back(token);
    }
    if (reversed) {
        it = words.end();
    } else {
        it = words.begin();
    }
}
```

The rest of the member functions are pretty simple:

```
/**
 True if pointer is at the beginning of vector
 */
bool WordCrawler::atBeginning() const {
    return it == words.begin();
}

/**
  Function that returns the string stored at the pointer's address
 */
std::string WordCrawler::operator*() const {
    return *it;
}

/**
  Function that increments the pointer back by one
 */
WordCrawler& WordCrawler::operator--() {
    if (!atBeginning())
        --it;
    return *this;
}
```

I'm finding that everything works fine on Xcode and cpp.sh, but on Visual Studio it throws a runtime error saying `vector iterators incompatible` at `atBeginning()` function. My assumption would be that this is because the code is reliant on some sort of undefined behavior, but as I am relatively new to C++ I'm not sure what it is.

I know that `it` is always an iterator of the `words` vector, and I know that `words` does not change after `it` has been initialized, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Full code at: http://codepad.org/mkN2cGaM

Comment: What import statements are you using?

Comment: @awiebe `iostream`, `vector`, `string`, `sstream`.

Comment: Added link to full source.

Comment: We don't want full source; we want a [MCVE]. You should already have constructed one during your own debugging session.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit did you follow the link? It is only the code I have already posed here, but all in one file, such that others may copy into their own dev environments without needing to piece this answer together. It is minimal as I only include the necessary methods/functions, complete as it compiles and runs, and verifiable as it exhibits the behavior I have described. It also provides answers to awiebe's question and any others like it.

Comment: Take a close look at this line, in `print_in_reverse()`: `while (!wc.atBeginning()); {`.

Comment: I think this whole atBeginning idea is going to run into off-by-one problems, when you come around to do the forward iteration version

Comment: @JustinTime my mistake. If you look at the linked code you'll see the original was ugly, so I edited in place on SO. Fixed.

Comment: @Jackson: It's not minimal, and it's an off-site link rather than being embedded _in_ your question. Other than that, perfect. Perhaps you confused SO for a personal helpdesk rather than a Q&A repository?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?  It works with 2015, testing with [Cloudapp](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) (can't link to specific examples here, just copy-paste), [Rextester](http://rextester.com/TUHSJ39750), and [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/EHlWC9).

Comment: @JustinTime 2013... student budget. Actually I don't even know how much VS costs. Helping a friend, thats what they have.

Comment: Ah.  Yeah, that matches up with M.M's answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I claim it is not impossible that some future C++ learner will encounter this issue with VS not performing copy elision and thereby invalidating their vector iterators. You seem to be someone who appreciates learning about iterator invalidation, so I'd think you'd agree.

Comment: @Jackson: Yes, it has future value, if you present it in the form of a [MCVE]. Obviously an off-site link may, among other things, be invalidated in the future, so that future C++ learner would be out of luck!

Comment: By the way you can get Visual Studio for free, so budget isn't relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your object has a rule of three violation - on copy/move construction the iterator will still point to the vector in the old object.

The line `WordCrawler wc = WordCrawler(in, true);` specifies a copy/move operation, triggering this problem. Most compilers perform copy elision here but I heard that older versions of MSVC don't, in debug mode anyway.

To fix this properly, I would recommend using an index instead of an iterator in the class.  If you really want to use the iterator you will need to implement your own copy-constructor and move-constructor.

Changing that line to `WordCrawler wc(in, true);` would probably fix this particular program but the same problem would be lurking still, and might show up when you make further modifications later.

Comment: So `WordCrawler wc(in,true);` would be a quick fix?

Comment: Interesting. In my forward version I used `for(WordCrawler wc = in; !wc.reachedEnd() ; wc ++ )`, does the black magic C++ type coercion with `WordCrawler wc = in` work in the same way as `WordCrawler wc(in, true);` would?

Comment: @Jackson `WordCrawler wc = in` means `WordCrawler wc = WordCrawler(in)`

Comment: A good point, but he's probably safe in this particular case, since most compilers will use copy elision for `wc`.

Comment: @JustinTime as mentioned in my answer, I have seen in other SO Q/As that MSVC sometimes doesn't

Comment: @M.M I think I missed that line, my bad.

Comment: Just did a test with an older version (VS 2010, specifically), and this does indeed appear to be a case where it won't perform copy elision.  A little research indicates that 2013 was one of the versions that didn't always do copy elision and/or RVO when it could, so I'd say you hit the nail on the head.